# Google Analytics iOS - Open URL Hangs

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

On click of a button, I send the user to an external URL (safari).  I was to track this action, so I include a call to google analytics right before I call openUrl()

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"action" action:@"button_press" label:@"link" value:nil] build]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

This successfully gets me to the url in safari, but on coming back to the app, it is just frozen.  I have tried wrapping it in dispatch_async main queue block, with no luck.

If I remove the google analytics tracker line, it works fine.  Is this a bug in google analytics?

Comment: When you remove "google analytics tracker line" do you also remove the createEventWithCategory line? If you don't your code is probably not making it the canOpenUrl if and openURL call.

Comment: I've debugged and seen the code finish to completion, so I know everything has run

Comment: Anybody could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution, although its not the best.  Basically, if I dispatch the tracking code by a second, the hanging does not happen.  I checked in my dashboard, and the call still gets tracked.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory(category, action: event, label: label, value: nil).build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

I hope google takes a look at this call, as this is not an optimal solution.